# Why is my yarnrc.yml file missing from my project?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

I'm on yarn version `3.2.0` and trying to deploy a project on Heroku and it's telling me that I need the `yarnrc.yml` file but it is missing. I've tried running `yarn`, `yarn install`, `yarn set version berry`, and `yarn set version stable` but the file will not auto generate. I also created a brand new project and tried `yarn init -2` but still no rc file.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem, I ended up creating the file by myself.
Take care, that the error message from Heroku is missleading and the file requires a prefixed dot: `.yarnrc.yml`

First line is for opting out of Plug&Play, second line points to the local yarn release (might depend on your version)

```yaml
nodeLinker: node-modules
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.1.cjs
```

Comment: This works for me, but you would still need to run `$ yarn install, and $ yarn set version berry`. Then you should be good to go

Comment: this worked for me. Created the file and only set the nodeLinker inside as stated in the documentation here https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#if-required-enable-the-node-modules-plugin